# In IP6 fe80::8a10:8fff:feb7:1632 > ff02::2: ICMP6, router solicitation , length 16

Tags: switch, juniper, juniper-ex

When I use command to capture the packages of interface `ae52.0` in my EX4300 gateway Switch (L3):

```
run monitor traffic interface ae52.0
```

I get many

```
In IP6 fe80::8a10:8fff:feb7:1632 > ff02::2: ICMP6, router solicitation , length 16
```

the `In` means the orientation into the `ae52.0`.

see my snapshot:

[image]

What's the meaning? how to fix it? seems this caused the the ae52.0 do not reply the arp response.

Comment: Please, never use an image for text. Simply copy the text and paste it into the question using the Preformatted-text option (`{}`).

Comment: I do not see a problem. You cannot look up DNS for a multicast address (even for IPv4), and IPv6 uses router solicitations, so you should see those. "_seems this caused the the ae52.0 do not reply the arp response._" There is no ARP for IPv6, so that statement does not make any sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ARP is an IPv4 process. You are seeing IPv6 traffic. (IPv4 and IPv6 don't share anything beyond the "I" and "P".)

What you are seeing is the normal initial messages from a host's interface coming online. Instead of waiting for an RA broadcast (*multicast* in v6), the host sends a *Router Solicitation* to trigger any routers to send one ahead of schedule. You don't appear to have IPv6 setup within your network, so these hosts will not have global (or Unique Local) addresses; they will have fe80... link-local addresses as already seen.